# Why CDC::IsPrinting() return FALSE when is from CPrintDialog::GetPrinterDC()?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm using

> CPrintDialog

to setup printer parameters and I get the DC with the GetPrinterDC() method.

```
CPrintDialog pd ( TRUE , PD_RETURNDC );
if ( pd.DoModal () == IDOK )
{
    HDC hDC = pd.GetPrinterDC();
    CDC printDC;
    printDC.Attach ( hDC );

    /*...*/
}
```

In my generic drawing function I want to know is the DC is used for printing. Then I call the method IsPrinting().

```
void drawSomething ( CDC& DC )
{
    if ( DC.IsPrinting () )
    {
        //Do some special drawing only for printer
    }
    //Do standard drawing
}
```

The IsPrinting () works perfectly when the DC cames from the document/view architecture by MFC. It doesn't work when is from the CPrintDialog. Why this? There's a way to have it works? I would like not to pass an extra flag to my drawing function.

Comment: It *looks* like it is something that the CDC should be able to figure out by itself.  But it is not, it only ever returns true if the CDC was created by MFC code that is dedicated to printing.  Specifically CView::OnFilePrint() and CPreviewView::SetPrintView().  Not a problem, since it is you that created the CDC, you also know whether or not it was made for printing.  You can set the `m_bPrinting` member to true yourself, it is public.

Comment: `AttachDC` has no way of knowing `HDC` is a printer dc, so you have to set `m_bPrinting` manually